# Does $\alpha$ need to be transcendental over F?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In the book there is this exercise:

Let E be an extension fiel of F, with $\alpha, \beta \in E$. Suppose $\alpha$ is transcendental over F but algebraic over $F(\beta)$. Show that $\beta$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$.

The suggested solution was:
[image]

It doesn't seem that they use that $\alpha$ is transcendental in F, or do they? Or is the statement valid without this assumption?

Comment: There is a polynomial P($\alpha$) = 0 with coefficients polynomials f($\beta$). You do just rewrite this polynomial to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, they use that hypothesis in the part

> *a polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients that are polynomials in $\beta$ can be formally rewritten as a polynomial in $\beta$ with
>   coefficients that are polynomials in $\alpha$*

to conclude that this new polynomial (seen in $(F[\alpha])[x]$) is not the zero polynomial. This is necessary to conclude that $\beta$ satisfy a **non-zero** polynomial over $F(\alpha)$ so $\beta$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim You're completely right! I'm sorry, I'll erase it right now. I think a counterexample goes that way.

Comment: Of course Alex. It was certainly a lapsus of Daniel.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez That's right. On the other hand, can you think a counterexmaple? I'm thinking and I can't find anything.

Comment: @DanielEscudero: doing so might be difficult. You'd have to ensure the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ divides all the coefficients of the polynomial obtained by rewriting as polynomial in $\beta$. I can't see of any easy way to rig this. Roots of unity might be a good place to start, but that's just an offhand guess.

Comment: Is the point that when we reqrite the poluynomial we have to make sure that not coefficients infront of each $\beta$ is zero? So we are using that $\alpha$ is transcendental in F, on each coefficient, not on the polynomial as a whole?

Comment: @user119615 That's right, it shows each coefficient cannot be zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!, very niced that you saw how it was needed!

Comment: @user119615 You're welcome. However, there's is something to do yet: Prove that it's not necessarily true if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.